# NoSuchMethodError when using Apache Tika

Tags: apache-tika

The following error is encountered when I extract the metadata of a JPEG image using Apache Tika

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.adobe.xmp.properties.XMPPropertyInfo.getValue()Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.drew.metadata.xmp.XmpReader.extract(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.extractMetadataFromJpegSegmentReader(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageMetadataExtractor.parseJpeg(ImageMetadataExtractor.java:91)
at org.apache.tika.parser.jpeg.JpegParser.parse(JpegParser.java:56)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120
```

Tika version being used: Tika 1.4

What is the cause of the error?

Also note that the metadata for an image that doesn't contain any XMP metadata is extracted by the API correctly. This error occurs only for those images that have XMP metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Tika uses the API : [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/) to extract metadata from image files.

The most likely reason for the cause is if one has both tika and the metadata-extractor libraries in their classpath. The binary for metadata-extractor may have been built using a different version of [XMPCore](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) library compared with the one that Tika uses.

Solution: remove metadata-extractor's library from your classpath.

The issue with incompatible usage of XMPCore libraries by the two projects isn't resolved:
https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/issues/detail?id=55

Comment: so which library do I need to remove? Because I cannot find anything other than `tika-app-1.10.jar` in my libraries

Comment: @ha9u63ar One possible reason could be that `metadata-extractor` is a transitive dependency via a different library in your classpath. Try viewing all transitive dependencies of your project and then see if you can find either a) metadata extractor library OR b) two different versions for `XMPCore`